# Как скрыть header на некоторых страницах сайта на yii

Tags: yii, php, layout, view

Для простоты упрощу задачу след. образом: Есть layout и в нем есть header. Нужно чтобы этот header не выводился на некоторых страницах. Как это лучше реализовать на yii?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете задать свойство в главном контроллере, от которого наследуются остальные (обычно он лежит в папке components)

```
protected $_showHeader = true;

public function setShowHeader($value)
{
    $this->_showHeader = (bool) $value;
    return $this;
}

public function getShowHeader()
{
    return $this->_showHeader;
}
```

В нужных экшенах сеттить значение для текущего свойства, что бы отключить header:

```
$this->setShowHeader(false);
```

И затем в layout проверять

```
<?php if($this->getShowHeader()):?>
    <header></header>
<?php endif;?>
```